# Returning JSON object from Django view to client via AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, django

Basically, I am trying to turn raw SQL query result to JSON object and then send it to client-side via AJAX.
Here is my view (I am using **Django 1.8.6**)

```
import MySQLdb
from django.db import connection
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
def test_view(request):
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute("select id, name from okved")
      data = cursor.fetchall
      json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
      return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

The respective URLConf

```
url(r'^test/$', test_view),
```

JQuery function

```
var test = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/test",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: "false",
        data:{},
        success:function(response)
        {
            alert("Test successful");
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

I am constantly getting **GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)** error, wheareas I follow all the recommendations that I have come across the previous threads here. I would really appreciate any help on this. I have blown my mind trying surfing Stackoverflow on this.

Comment: What's your question? What error have you got? Please edit your question to reflect those.

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: I think `fetchall` is a function (`fetchall()`), BTW, this error is not related to JSON response, you have a logic error in your view, if possible, post your full traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, 500 error is just an error code, django would give you stacktrace of where the error happens in the function stack, you should learn to read that and find where the error happens.

From you code sounds like you are trying to use `serializers` to serialize a raw query result. This wouldn't work because the raw result is a tuple of tuples, each sub tuple is a record returned from your database. Django `serializers` is only good at serializing objects queried from ORM. You'd better go with `json.dumps()` method. Here's last few lines in your views.py:

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
json_data = json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Here's the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/) for django serializer.

Comment: I don't think so, when javascript loads json string, it becomes just a data structure, there's no attributes to it, thus no way to do dot notation.